# Random UICollectionViewCell Sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewController`, and I want to make the cells inside of it have random sizes, but keep the aspect ratio 16:9. I would like the widths to range anywhere from 100 to 200. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let widths = [100, 130, 200, 170, 150]

    let number = widths[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(widths.count)))]

    return CGSize(width: number, height: (1080 / 1920) * number)

}
```

This did not work, and it would seem that all of the cells would have the same random width. I want them all to have different widths. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you aren't getting cell is the height for cell is always set to zero because while calculating height (1080 / 1920) * number,  the integer result of (1080 / 1920) will be always zero so number multiplied by 0 will end up with height 0 for the cell. Try the below code.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

  let widths = [100, 130, 200, 170, 150]
  let number = widths[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(widths.count)))]
  let height: Double = Double((1080 / 1920) * number)
  let size = CGSize(width: number, height: Int(height))
  return size
}
```